# Prove that two groups act in the same way

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ are finite cyclic groups acting on a set $A$. The properties (number of orbits and their length) of  $G:A$ are known. About $H$ I know only that it is finite and cyclic (don't know the order, but it is supposingly the same as order of $G$) and how it acts on each element of $A$. I want to prove that $H:A$ has the same number of orbits and lengths as $G:A$, but the only approach I see is to construct a bijective mapping $\varphi:A\to A$ such that $ga = \varphi^{-1}h \varphi a$, where $a\in A$, $g\in G$, $h\in H$. Are there other general ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: No. Unless actions of $G$ and $H$ are somehow related there's absolutely nothing you can deduce from one knowing the other.

Comment: For example, it's consistent with the knowledge you have that one of $G$ and $H$ has a trivial action on $A$ (fixing every point) and the other does not. Unless you have enough information to distinguish even this particular case, the general question seems futile.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.